# Docker does not recognize bash variable used as argument

Tags: bash, docker

I have a bash variable A: `A="-v ~/share:/home/docker/share"`

I want to use it as a part of the command which creates a new docker container:

`docker run --rm -it $A ubuntu`
But docker says, `~` is not a valid character for path (`create  ~/share: " ~/share" includes invalid characters for a local volume name`)

If I run the same command without using `$A` it works:

`docker run --rm -it -v ~/share:/home/docker/share ubuntu`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
A="-v ~/share:/home/docker/share"
```

to

```
A="-v $HOME/share:/home/docker/share"
```

`~` will not be expanded when you store it into a variable, it will remain a literal `~`. Using `$HOME` will avoid this.

Comment: @acro444 is correct. From man sh, Tilde Expansion (substituting a user's home directory) A word beginning with an unquoted tilde character (~) is subjected to tilde expansion.

Comment: In general, one should not use a regular variable to store multiple arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a regular variable to hold multiple command arguments; use an array instead.

```
A=(-v ~/share:/home/docker/share)
docker run --rm -it "${A[@}}" ubuntu
```

This will work even if an argument contains a character that the shell would otherwise interpret specially after the parameter is expanded.